# Metodo de mensajes predetermiados c# asp

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero crear una clase Mensajes que contenga un método donde dentro de mi controlador cuando mande a llamar dicho método metodo mensajeCreado (por decir un ejemplo)

me ejecute en mi controlador,

```
return RedirectToAction("Index").Success("Registro creado con exito");
```

habia hecho algo similar hace tiempo en c# quedo asi

```
    public static void MensajeAlerta(String Mensaje,String cabecera)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Mensaje, cabecera, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

    }
```

pero no encuentro como seria en ASP.net Mvc
Pienso que entre los parámetros debería mandar el controlador

Comment: De WinForms -> WebForms -> MVC5 hay **muchas** diferencias. El paradigma es distinto y la forma de pensar debe serlo también. Yo recomendaría devolver una Vista Parcial, que pueda ser renderizada desde el controlador. Otros podrían recomendar un modal de boostrap. Alguien más podría recomentar jqueryUI para un message box rápido. No hay un *método de mensajes predeterminado* en mvc. Todo depende de qué, **específicamente**, quieres mostrar.

Comment: especificamente lo que quisera mostrar es una alert que ya mando desde el controlador como se muestra en el primer fragmento pero al tener un modelo muy grande quisiera estandarisar los mensajes solo creando el mensaje una vez y llamarlo solo en la accion que corresponda  Create = alert " creado con exito " edit = alert "editado con exito" etc algo asi

Comment: Y ese alert, cuándo debería mostrarse? Después de un postback? Como resultado de una llamada ajax? Cómo debería mostrarse? Cuando dices un alert, te refieres al comando `alert('este es un alert en el navegador')` de la consola de los navegadores? O quieres que se muestre en un componente tuyo? Mis preguntas son para buscar una mejor manera de ayudarte. A como está escrito, hay demasiadas posibles respuestas. Tal vez [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) te ayude a hacerla más específica